# Displaying multiple results from query to array object

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building the following PHP application. I have a function in a class named Board. In the function you'll see a Query performing an Inner Join with the table users to associate the ID's and filter. This is the function;

**Solution given by A-C**

> $boards = $statementBoards->fetch**All**(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

```
public function loadBoards($userID)
{
        $conn = Db::getInstance();
        $statementBoards = $conn->prepare("SELECT board.boardID, 
        board.userID, board.private, board.boardTitle, users.firstname, 
        users.lastname FROM
        board INNER JOIN users ON board.userID=users.id WHERE 
        board.userID = :userID;");
        $statementBoards->bindValue(':userID', $userID);
        $statementBoards->execute();
        $boards = $statementBoards->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $boards;
    }
```

In the front end I'm printing the following:

```
 $b = new Board();
 $userID = $_SESSION['id'];
 $boards= $b->loadBoards($userID);
 var_dump($boards);
```

Which gives me the following result:

```
array(6) { ["boardID"]=> string(2) "29" ["userID"]=> string(2) "93" 
["private"]=> string(1) "1" ["boardTitle"]=> string(14) "MyBoard" 
["firstname"]=> string(5) "NameTest" ["lastname"]=> string(5) 
"TestName" }
```

However, the query should show multiple results and so I was expecting multiple arrays. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by multiple results?

Comment: There are multiple lines in the table associated with the same userID that should be displayed on the front end

Comment: when you use join, the results returned will be joined into one query/result set. so there won't be two results set from the two separate tables.

Comment: I understand but still why is the second result not showing when I use var_dump?

Comment: I think OP is just expecting multiple rows to be returned -- try looping and/or [`fetchAll`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Yes this did the trick! Sorry to bother you guys, I should've looked more carefully.